# Why are infinite-dimensional vector spaces usually equipped with additional structure?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, soft-question

In a first course in linear algebra, it is common for instructors to mostly restrict their attention to finite-dimensional vector spaces. These vector spaces are usually not assumed to be equipped with any additional structure, such as an inner product, norm, or a topology. On the other hand, it seems that when infinite-dimensional vector spaces are encountered in later courses, it is much more common to equip with them additional structure. Why is this? A partial answer might be that infinite-dimensional vector spaces are often studied in functional analysis, where extra structure is needed to properly define analytical concepts such as infinite series. However, I would have expected that "pure" infinite-dimensional vector spaces have a use in some area of mathematics.

I have now also asked this on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452855/why-do-infinite-dimensional-vector-spaces-usually-have-additional-structure?).

Comment: All norms/topologies, etc on a finite dimensional vector space (over R or C) are equivalent/the same, so one often does not need to specify one.

Comment: If you deal with infinite dimensional spaces you need to define convergence, hence you will need some topology.

Comment: There is no one line answer. Infinite dimensional spaces allow a lot of behaviours that cannot occur in finite dimensions. For example, in finite dimensions the closed unit ball is compact.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: I agree that it would be silly to not use the norm in that specific case. My question is more: why do "pure" infinite-dimensional vector spaces not arise more frequently in mathematics? It seems that the majority of the time infinite-dimensional vector spaces "crop up", they come naturally with some additional structure.

Comment: I would guess because infinite dimensional vector spaces is too broad a topic - there isn't much you can do with them in terms of solving the kinds of problems you can solve with matrices. The main infinite-dimensional vector spaces that don't have additional topological structure are polynomial and power series rings. But these are rings, so there is still additional structure.

Comment: Vector spaces with uncountable dimension tend to not have good sets of basis vectors. The basis sets exist only in theory, using axiom of choice. But adding topology can give you computable dense bases, like the Fourier basis for $L^2[0,1],$ which isn't a vector-space basis, but is "good enough."

Comment: Basically, infinite dimensional vector spaces only allow the most generic vector space arguments. Any theorem about vector spaces in general applies to infinite-dimensional vector spaces, but there isn't much of interest that you can prove, and what you can prove tends to either relatively obvious or non-constructive.

Comment: Also finite-dimensional vector spaces often carry an additional structure, e.g., a bilinear algebra product. Examples are Lie algebras, associative algebras, Poisson algebras and so on.

Comment: Yeah. But we solve a lot of problems about finite-dimensional vector spaces that are independent of such things. We don't do so for infinite-dimensional vector spaces. @DietrichBurde

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I found all of your comments to be very useful, thank you. If you have the time, I would appreciate it if you could convert them into answer (but of course you are not obliged to!).

Comment: An integral is a limit. Infinite sums are limits. Limits require topology. Infinite-dimensional spaces are much more powerful if you add topology.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Consider the following example.

Vectors over, say, the field $\mathbb{R}$, with finite dimension $n$, we'd like to prototypically understand as lists, or tuples:

$$\mathbf{v} = (a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n).$$

Note here that the right hand is literally a tuple of reals; it is the "meat" of what the objects in the space "$\mathbb{R}^n$" "really are". The reals $a_j$ are the *components* of the vector, which are not the same *concept* as *coordinates*, which refer to the values $b_j$ when $\mathbf{v}$ is expressed in a basis $\mathcal{B}$:

$$\mathbf{v} = b_1 \mathbf{b}_1 + b_2 \mathbf{b}_2 + \cdots + b_n \mathbf{b}_n$$

where $\mathcal{B} = \{ \mathbf{b}_1, \mathbf{b}_2, \cdots, \mathbf{b}_n \}$. Given a basis, any vector has coordinates, but *not all* vectors have *components*, because the elements of the actual vector space set need not be just tuples.

But here's the thing: it's quite obvious that, *in this case*, we have a basis where that the coordinates and components are identical, namely:

$$\begin{matrix}
\mathbf{e}_1 := (1, 0, 0, \cdots, 0)\\
\mathbf{e}_2 := (0, 1, 0, \cdots, 0)\\
\cdots\\
\mathbf{e}_n := (0 ,0, 0, \cdots, 1)\end{matrix}$$

Then the vector $(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_j \mathbf{e}_j$ and the coordinates and components are identical. We call this the **standard basis** for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Now,** consider *infinite* dimension. It's quite natural to extend vectors with a *finite* tuple of $n$ reals, to an *infinite* tuple or perhaps as some might be more comfortable saying, a "sequence" (they are "equivalent" though one might call them different "data types"):

$$\mathbf{v} = (a_1, a_2, a_3, \cdots)$$

where there are now *infinitely* many *components* $a_j$. We'd **like**, then, *by analogy with before*, to write down a basis in the form

$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{e}_1 := (1, 0, 0, 0, \cdots)\\
\mathbf{e}_2 := (0, 1, 0, 0, \cdots)\\
\mathbf{e}_3 := (0, 0, 1, 0, \cdots)\\
\cdots\end{align}$$

so that we could say

$$\mathbf{v} = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i \mathbf{e}_i.$$

The problem though, is that by definition, an infinite summation like this requires us to take the following limit:

$$\mathbf{v} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \mathbf{e}_i\right).$$

And the thing in the brackets *is a vector*, so what we have is a *limit of vectors*.

But limits don't make sense unless you have some way to compare vectors for notions like proximity, or "approximate-ness", or what have you!

Thus, if we want to be able to use the "basis" we have given above, we *must* add some extra structure to the space, which specifies how that limits or approximations are to work, i.e. "who is within some tolerance of who", so that the infinite sum is both defined at all, *and* so that it generates the result we'd like it to generate.

So no, the vector space itself doesn't "need" a topology, but suitably building one on it lets us do a *lot* of stuff we'd "like" to be able to do but otherwise wouldn't.